# How can I make type inference work in a generic method?

Tags: dart

I tried running the following method, which checks the type of a `dynamic` parameter and returns a value based on the generic type parameter `T`:

```
T mySpecialCastMethod<T>(dynamic value){
  if( T == String ){
    return '$value';
  }
  
  return null;
}
```

and got

```
A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'T'
```

I was expecting the compiler to be able to see that `T` must be a `String` inside the `if` statement, which implies that `'$value'` would be a valid return value.

Why doesn't it work, and can I make it work?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @AlexRadzishevsky Added some more info. I want to check the type of `T` and return a value of that type. For the sake of simplicity and to not confuse readers, I've just included the most basic of cases - checking if `T` is `String`, and in that case returning a `String`. I'm surprised this doesn't compile.

Comment: Can you post the actual code? `'$value'` won't compile as it is using character literal quotes.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen This is the actual code I was trying to compile. Maybe I'm asking too much of the compiler to be able to infer that `'$value'.runtimeType == T`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explicitly cast return value to T

```dart
T myMethod<T>(dynamic value){
  if(T == String){
    return '$value' as T;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: This works - but why is it needed when `'$value'.runtimeType == String` and `T == String`?

Comment: As I got your idea is that you want to return String values, otherwise return nulls. If that is the case then you do not need generics at all. But I assuming that in future you would want to extend this to support other types. So in that case "T == String" will just tell you what type you specified when calling method. '$value'.runtimeType == String will always return true, so it is useless.

Comment: You're exactly right. But what I don't understand is why the compiler can't see that `'$value'` (which is a `String`) is a valid return value inside the `if` statement, which is only executed if `T` is `String`. In other words, `'$value'` is `String`, `T` is `String`, so `'$value'` should be a valid return value even without specifically using `as T `, right?

Comment: In principle, the compiler could, but automatic type promotion occurs only under specific circumstances (such as from `is` checks and not from `==` checks), and this simply isn't one of them. (As another example, [automatic type promotion can occur only between related types](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34018#issuecomment-782767554)).